# Using group by with pivot and unpivot in sql server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I'm using pivot and unpivot in sql and have a dynamic query for it. But my problem is, I am getting an error saying **The column 'May-2015' was specified multiple times for 'P'.**. Could you guys help me out using **GROUP BY** for **Month**? Query is as below:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+'],[' , '') + [Month]
FROM Table1
SELECT @listStr = '[' + @listStr + ']'

DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(8000)
SET @Query = '
select [System],' + @listStr +
'from
(
  select [Month],Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4     
  from Table1
) as T
unpivot
(
  Value for [System] in (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)
) as U
pivot
(
  sum(Value) for [Month] in (' + @listStr + ')
) as P'

EXECUTE(@Query)
```

Thanks

Comment: What does @listStr contain?

Comment: It Contains the list of months (csv) from the table1 (example: Jan-2015,Feb-2014 etc). @JamesZ

Comment: Well yes but does it contain the same value multiple times, like the error suggests

Comment: It does contain same months as there is other column in the table called "track". The values are defined trackwise @JamesZ

Comment: Well then just select distinct months, that will fix the issue with duplicate columns. No idea what you're supposed to do with this "track" since it's not included in your SQL in any way.

Comment: just replace your entire @listStr logic with `SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ',' , '') + QUOTENAME([Month]) FROM Table1 GROUP BY [Month]`